# Stripe.js - Resolve Cannot read property 'stripeToken' of undefined

Tags: javascript, express, stripe-payments

I'm building my first basic Express app using Stripe's `Checkout`. The app renders correctly but when I submit the form, I get an error on both `stripeToken` and `stripeEmail`. I'm not sure why it's not passing through. Any help?

My app:

```js
const keyPublishable = process.env.PUBLISHABLE_KEY;
const keySecret = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

const app = require("express")();
const stripe = require("stripe")(keySecret);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get("/", (req, res) =>
  res.render("index.ejs", {keyPublishable}));

app.post("/charge", (req, res) => {
  let amount = 500;

  stripe.customers.create({
     email: req.body.stripeEmail,
    source: req.body.stripeToken
  })
  .then(customer =>
    stripe.charges.create({
      amount,
      description: "Sample Charge",
         currency: "usd",
         customer: customer.id
    }))
  .then(charge => res.render("charge.ejs"));
});

app.listen(7000);
```

and my `index.ejs`

```html
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_Gbu2akKhNgGjbKi4LPxOOWqc"
    data-amount="500"
    data-name="Ojoseyewear"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that the Stripe docs example did not include bodyParser.

`req.Body` just returns an object from the form submission. Without bodyParser, there's no way to get those two strings.

Add this to `app.js` and you're golden:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```