# stripeToken and chargeAmount undefined in checkout page

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to set up stripe to take dynamic payment amounts from an HTML form. This form is on the checkout.html page shown below:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <title>checkout</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
    </header>

    <body>

        <form id="myForm" action="/charge" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />
            <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail" />

            <input type="text" id="item1price" value="253">
            <input type="text" id="item2price" value="167">

            <button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

            <script>

                  //change secret key later!
                  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                  key: 'pk_test',
                  image: 'img/stripe.png',
                  locale: 'auto',
                  token: function(token) {
                    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
                    // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
                    $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
                    $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);

                    $("#myForm").submit();
                  }
                });

            document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

                //add up each price in array to get total cost
                var total = 100;
                // ...

                //insert total variable into hidden html text field
                function insertText(){
                    document.getElementById('chargeAmount').value = total;
                }
                insertText();

              // Open Checkout with further options:
              handler.open({
                name: 'test company',
                description: "test desc",
                amount: total * 100
              });
              e.preventDefault();
            });

            // Close Checkout on page navigation:
            window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
              handler.close();
            });
            </script>
            <input type="hidden" id="chargeAmount" name="chargeAmount" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also have this code in my server.js:

```
app.get('/pay', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile( __dirname + "/checkout.html" );
});

app.get('/paysuccess', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile( __dirname + "/paySuccess.html" );
});

app.post('/charge', function (req, res) {
  var token = req.body.stripeToken;
  console.log(token);
  var chargeAmount = req.body.chargeAmount;
  console.log(chargeAmount);
  var charge = stripe.charges.create({
      amount: chargeAmount,
      currency: "usd",
      source: token
  }, function(err, charge){
      if(err & err.type ==="StripeCardError"){
          console.log("your card was declined.");
      }
  });  
    res.redirect('/paysuccess');
})
```

and when I browse to localhost/pay, checkout.html shows up. I enter in the info in the boxes for the price, I have my code to add up the prices entered in the form and return the total, enter in the test payment card info, and then it takes me to the /paysuccess page. But the console says that both chargeAmount and stripeToken are undefined. I have them logged in the /charge function. I took some of the proprietary code out that I deemed to be unrelevant, but can anyone see an issue in my code as to why stripeToken and chargeAmount are undefined when I call them with `req.body.stripeToken` and `req.body.chargeAmount`? Thanks.

EDIT - I unhid all the html forms to see what their values were. At page load the stripeToken and stripeEmail values were empty but after finishing the test payment with the test cards, they get populated. I believe my error lies where it gets the values of the html forms. I saw this post: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712850/stripe-js-resolve-cannot-read-property-stripetoken-of-undefined?rq=1` and added that answer to my code. It seemed to work, but now I'm faced with an error saying that err is null.

```
if(err & err.type ==="StripeCardError"){
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null
```

The line in question is in the /charge function on my server.js.

Answer (score 0):

`stripe.charges.create` is asynchronous, so you're hitting `res.redirect` before you ever get the chargeToken value. You're also not passing it back in your response, so I'm not sure where you expect to be pulling it from.